# JustPy: How we configure the justpy.env for the session timeout configuration

Tags: python-3.x, justpy

I want to add the timeout for session in my justpy project but didn't understand the how the configure the justpy.env in justpy.
Thank you.

I have added the justpy.env file in my project directory, but I am not understanding how justpy knows the session related configuration in that file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.